# How rude is "to eat like a pig"?

Tags: idioms, politeness

How rude is it to say :

> People eat crabs like a pig.

Maybe it's not rude in plural sense like the above example but when you talk directly to someone?

Also other terms which relate humans to animals, "to eat like a horse" and "to eat like a bird".

Comment: Well, if a sentence includes *pig*, It is generally rude in somewhere.

Comment: I don't think you would say "The accepted way to eat crabs on Lake Pontchartrain is like a pig," even if it were true. So yes, I would have to say it is indeed rude.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I read an article which has a sentence like "people eat (something) like a pig", that's why I wondered and asked here, plus I didn't force you to answer this question. But honestly, I've never seen a pig and a pig eating, really sorry.

Comment: I was thinking of "to eat like a pig" as to eat something in a greedy way or something, that can be polite.

Comment: @Gigli Don't mind him. I thought it was an interesting question (which is of course why I answered it).

Comment: To me it sounds better (though no less rude) to say "people eat like pigs" rather than "like a pig" - since *people* is plural, it sounds more natural to pluralise *pig* too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Eating like a pig](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/eat+like+a+pig) is quite insulting as it implies messiness and poor manners.

> The feudal lord ate like a pig, tearing off hunks of meat with his fists, slobbering and licking his fingers, and wiping his face with his sleeve.

You are right though, that when used in a general sense ("People eat crabs like pigs."), it is not particularly offensive.

[Eating like a horse](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/eat+like+a+horse) (eating a lot) and [eating like a bird](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/eat+like+a+bird) (eating very little) are not necessarily insulting, since they refer to the quantity rather than the style of eating.  This can be nearly complimentary:

> My son is growing like a weed because he eats like a horse.
>
> She was a sweet, dainty thing who ate like a bird.

Or fairly insulting:

> She's fat because she eats like a horse!
>
> She's skin and bones because she eats like a bird.

"Eating like a horse" can be insulting because of its relationship to gluttony, or complimentary in the sense of having a good appetite.  Likewise, "eating like a bird" can be insulting because it can mean that a person is being picky about food, or complimentary in the sense of not being greedy.

Comment: +1 I'd add that eating like a horse is more insulting than eating like a bird - eating a lot is considered to be worse, than eating very little.

Comment: @Philoto good point, I'll edit.

Comment: ironically (yes, I know), a bird eats much more, relative to its own weight, than a pig, horse or human.

Comment: Note that it is much less rude to say "pig out", and most of these terms are generally not so rude if you are talking about yourself ("I pigged out on candy last night").

Comment: So "People eat crabs like pigs" is just a general statement, and not particularly offensive? I never saw pigs wear a bib, or use claw crackers, finger bowls, and napkins. I must lead a sheltered life.

Comment: @Philoto: If anything, I'd say *eating like a bird* is generally 'well-meant'; it often carries the implication that the speaker cares about the well-being of the person, and thinks they would be better off if they could manage to eat a little more.

Comment: @FumbleFingers agreed

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes,  "People eat crabs like pigs" smacks of "Fruit flies like a banana."  It is one of those sentences that no-one would ever say in real life except perhaps as a joke or a linguistic exemplar.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant how rude is it to use the expression "eat like a pig"?  Obviously so long as you're not insulting someone currently in the room with you, it's perhaps a little informal but not particularly rude.

Comment: counterpoint: *Your wife eats like a pig,* would be considered extremely rude, though she be absent from the room.

Comment: -1, rudeness of an expression is measured when addressing someone to their face (as it will eventually be judged when it finds its way to the addressed); otherwise nothings that is said of anyone (behind their backs and for example in the company of their enemies) would not be considered rude.

Comment: I thought that was obvious.  Even if the "eat like a pig" phrase didn't refer to anyone in the room or to anyone who's related to anyone in the room or anyone who knows someone in the room or to anyone who once saw that someone on tv somewhere a couple years go, you could still stomp on the man's toes after having said it and come across as rude.  Yet my point was another, and if you weren't busy finding counterexamples you'd get my point.

Comment: @Unreason - In fact so long as you're not using it as an insult, it isn't rude.  "My dog eats like a pig."  It's informal perhaps, but nobody's going to throw water in your face unless you nickname your wife "dog".